# Download UICollectionViewCell images via authenticated NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, uicollectionview, basic-authentication

How do I download multiple small images from server with `HTTP` basic authentication and load them asynchronously into `UICollectionView`. The code below works well for server without any authentication, but files will be stored behind Basic auth.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BrowseCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *fileName = [files objectAtIndex:row]; //NSArray *files
    NSString *filePath = [thumbDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somethng.com/thumbs/%@", fileName];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
            [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
                [cell setNeedsLayout];
            });
        });
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }
    cell.imageName = fileName;

    return cell;
}
```

How do I combine `NSURLConnection`, that covers authenticationChallenge, with `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method in order to load each image into cell as soon as it's downloaded?

Does it make sense to subclass `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and send indexPath to reload cell from within that other class? Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [this library](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) when I'm downloading and caching images. The implementation is as easy as:

```
cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.somethng.com/thumbs/%@", fileName] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

The library will cache the images for you. You can also use the block methods in the library if you need to know when the image loaded.

Comment: I actually reuse the downloaded images in different parts of app and want the app to run on- and offline. How do I permanently save images for offline use and access them by filename with SDWebImage?